# How is the statusUpdate field populated for Workfront issues, tasks and project objects?

Tags: attask, workfront-api

The issue, task, and project objects have a field called "statusUpdate". This field does not seem to return the most recent comment on an issue, task or project. I'm looking at an issue, the most recent comment in the UI was 9/29/2015, but the comment returned in the "statusUpdate" field via the API is from 7/25/2014.

At first I thought that the "statusUpdate" field is only updated when the status of the record is changed at the time the comment/update is made. However, in the same issue I'm looking at, there is a comment from 1/9/2015 that happened at the same time as a status update, but that comment is not what is returned in the "statusUpdate" field. Only the 7/25/2014 comment.

Does the "statusUpdate" field only update when set the status in the "Update status" form at the time the update is made? In other words, if I make an update on a record, and the status changes automatically as a part of that update, my update won't be returned in the "statusUpdate" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking at this yesterday. The Last Note object gets updated every time an update is made by ANYONE. The Status Update field, on the other hand, gets updated every time is made by the person who has been Assigned to the object (e.g. Task Assigned To).

Regards,
Doug Den Hoed
CEO
AtAppStore Inc.